# how to multiline data comes from database

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm retrieving an article from my db but it appears in a too long **one line** ! ,so I want to display it in a **multiline** way in my webpage
I'm using a datalist element to receive and show the data retrieved from db

```
 articlesDL.DataSource = DS.select_all_articles();
    articlesDL.DataBind();
```

and that's what my datalist appear in tags :

```
<asp:DataList ID="articlesDL" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="50px" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/"+Eval("imageurl")+".jpg" %>' Width="50px" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/reviewart.aspx?id="+Eval("articleid") %>' Text='<%# Eval("articlebody") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Show the source, the input, desired output and actual output. In short, show an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I edited the question ... but that won't help ... I know I should use css but I don't know how ! ( what to type ?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width to the panel where you are showing the data.

```
<div ID="articlesDL">

</div>
<style>
    #articlesDL
    {
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
```